# python: list changes when global edited

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = [1]

def do():
    global a
    b=a
    print b
    a[0] = 2
    print b

do()
```

outputs:
1
2

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that 'a' is a global list.
Could someone please explain to me why the variable b changes when the global changes. And how i could possibly stop it from happening?

an extension to the question:
how would you handle further nesting, such as:

```
a = []
b = []
def do():
    global a, b
    b.append(a[:])
    print a, b
    a[0][0] +=1
    print a, b

a.append([1])
do()
```

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

In this line `b=a` you essentially create a reference b, which points to a. This in python does not create a new copy of the list, but just creates a new link to it.

If you want to create a copy of `a` then you need to do it explicitly. Using list comprehensions, you can do it in this way :

```
b = a[:]
```

This will create a copy of a which will be referenced by b. See it in action :

---

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = a #Same list
>>> a[0] = 2
>>> b
[2] #Problem you are experiencing
```

You can see for yourself whether they refer to the same object or not by :

```
>>> a is b
True
```

The true signifies that they refer to the same object.

```
>>> b = a[:] #Solution <<--------------
```

Doing the same test again :

```
>>> a is b
False
```

And problem solved. They now refer to different objects.

```
>>> b
[2]
>>> a[0] = 3 #a changed
>>> a
[3]
>>> b
[2] #No change here
```

Comment: thank you, I thought this may be the case, wasn't sure how to get around it though.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `b = a` you are copying the reference to a list object that is held in `a` to `b`, so they point at the same list.  The changes to the underlying object will be reflected by either reference.

If you want to create a copy of the list use

```
b = list(a)
```

or, a method that will work on *most* objects:

```
import copy
b = copy.copy(a)
```

Comment: For sequences, you should use slicing as per the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid to be nit-picky the link says can not should.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding of python's variable model. This is the [article](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) I read that made it click for me (the sections "Other languages have variables" and "Python has names").

Comment: You should provide an extract

Comment: It's two paragraphs long and it has lots of pretty pictures. What would be the point of copy-pasting it when the link is right there?

Comment: See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156003/copying-webpage-content-is-fine-but-linking-to-the-web-page-is-considered-wrong